# Postbuild Event Copy build output to parent sibling undertermined folder

Tags: regex, visual-studio, xcopy, post-build-event

I have two solutions, WildCougarFarm and WildLionFarm both depending on a shared library

```
\Folder 1
    \WildCougarFarm
    \WildSharedLib (Separate Solution)
\Folder 2
    \WildLionFarm
    \WildSharedLib (Separate Solution)
```

When \WildSharedLib is built I want to run a post build script that automatically copies the output directories contents to the sibling **\Wild[Lion|Cougar]Farm** solution folder. Depending on whether WildLionFarm exists, I want it to copy with say wildHorseFarm in future.

I need an xcopy expression with a regex but xcopy doesn't support this.

Any ideas how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

This is pretty cool, because it uses a foreach type loop... so we ask if the parent folder of the solution contains any folders that end in farm. For any returned it will execute the xcopy statement to copy the files to that folder.

```
for /d %%a in ($(SolutionDir)..\*farm) do xcopy $(TargetDir)*.* "%%a\dependancies" /s /e /f /h /k /y /i
```